# What does the following error "com.apple.kextd[38]: Unable to resolve raw path /System/Library/Extensions/ni488lock.kext." mean?

Tags: python, macos, kernel-extension

I am running the following commands:

```
from pyvisa.vpp43 import visa_library
visa_library.load_library("/Library/Frameworks/Visa.framework/VISA")
import visa
print visa.get_instruments_list()
```

Reference: http://www.rau-deaver.org/Mac-PyVISA.html

## system logs

com.apple.kextd[38]: Unable to resolve raw path /System/Library/Extensions/ni488lock.kext.

ReportCrash[395]: Saved crash report for Python[383] version 2.7.2 (2.7.2) to /Users//Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Python_2013-02-27-175134_Motions-Mac-mini.crash

## crash logs

```
Process:         Python [383]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.2 (2.7.2)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [294]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Library/Frameworks/nipalu.framework/Versions/1/nipalu
PlugIn Identifier: com.ni.framework.nipalu
PlugIn Version:    2.7.0 (2.7.0f0)

Date/Time:       2013-02-27 17:51:31.185 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
/Library/Frameworks/ni488.framework/NI488
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x92f3aa6a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9639facf pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x963d64f8 abort + 168
3   com.ni.framework.nipalu         0x006664b1 libSetSSPackageClientLoadStatus(long) + 129
4   com.ni.framework.NI488          0x007cafdf __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) + 45
5   dyld                            0x8fe9bcda ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 230
6   dyld                            0x8fe9bfde ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 64
7   dyld                            0x8fe98268 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 356
8   dyld                            0x8fe980ba ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 62
9   dyld                            0x8fe8ce0b dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 88
10  dyld                            0x8fe92605 dlopen + 718
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x987c9dbe dlopen + 68
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x908931f2 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadFramework + 210
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x90858746 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 822
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x90858396 CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 70
15  com.ni.framework.VISA           0x003a78d6 visaLibSymbol + 68
16  com.ni.framework.GpibPassport   0x00544375 bundleLoad + 811
17  com.ni.framework.GpibPassport   0x00544f5b bundleLoad + 3857
18  com.ni.framework.GpibPassport   0x00543808 0x53a000 + 38920
19  com.ni.framework.VISA           0x003bbb9a viUnlock + 673
20  com.ni.framework.VISA           0x003a23d9 visaRegisterOper + 5942
21  com.ni.framework.VISA           0x003be5e1 viFindRsrc + 1153
22  libffi.dylib                    0x0038191d ffi_call_SYSV + 29
23  libffi.dylib                    0x00381c0b ffi_call + 125
24  _ctypes.so                      0x003722d5 _ctypes_callproc + 807
25  _ctypes.so                      0x0036c61d 0x36a000 + 9757
26  org.python.python               0x0009ce1e PyObject_Call + 97
27  org.python.python               0x001470c9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8651
28  org.python.python               0x0014ae37 0x8d000 + 777783
29  org.python.python               0x00146f77 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8313
30  org.python.python               0x00144eb2 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1777
31  org.python.python               0x0014aea8 0x8d000 + 777896
32  org.python.python               0x00146f77 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 8313
33  org.python.python               0x00144eb2 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1777
34  org.python.python               0x001447bc PyEval_EvalCode + 87
35  org.python.python               0x000b510e 0x8d000 + 164110
36  org.python.python               0x000b4f6d PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 492
37  org.python.python               0x000b4a05 PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 205
38  org.python.python               0x000b4890 PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 70
39  org.python.python               0x000d7c66 Py_Main + 2962
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x987ca725 start + 1
```

Comment: Does the bundle `/System/Library/Extensions/ni488lock.kext` exist? It sounds as if your library has a kernel component that needs to be loaded, and that kernel component might not have been correctly installed? Try loading it explicitly with `sudo kextutil /System/Library/Extensions/ni488lock.kext` to see if that works.

Comment: I tried and got the following message:
$ sudo kextutil /System/Library/Extensions/ni488lock.kext
No kernel file specified, using '/mach_kernel'

Comment: Okay, that would indicate that the kext is correctly loadable. I'm unfortunately not familiar with the VISA library, but from the stack trace it seems you should be looking for the problem in the library's `libSetSSPackageClientLoadStatus()` function; the kextd output might not be directly related.

Comment: Actually, I was using OS X 10.8.2 (which only supports 64 bit mode). So, I downgraded to OS X 10.7.x and set the kernel to 32 bit mode. And all seems to be working great! Thanks for your help though

Comment: Ah, sounds as if you just need an updated version of the driver then.